# Woocommerce: get availability remaining from fixed quantity

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using the following function in order to customize the display of available products/seats left, using Woocommerce.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_availability', 'custom_get_availability', 1, 2);

function custom_get_availability( $availability, $_product ) {
  global $product;
  $stock = $product->get_total_stock();

  if ( $_product->is_in_stock() ) $availability['availability'] = __($stock . ' seats left', 'woocommerce');
  if ( !$_product->is_in_stock() ) $availability['availability'] = __('No more seats', 'woocommerce');

  return $availability;
}
```

In addition I would like to be able to display the original quantity of products/seats. Like this: **"xx seats left of yy total seats"**

Is there something like: `$product->get_original_stock();` that I can use?

**SOLUTION:**

`$original_stock = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'original_stock', true );`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Woocommerce doesn't keep any record of original stock quantity because that number is always decremented upon purchase. However, you could use [custom fields](https://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields). Add the field in dashboard and then retrieve it like so:

```
$custom_attributes = get_post_custom();
print $custom_attributes['original_stock'];
```

Comment: This is how I solved it: `$original_stock = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'original_stock', true );`
I learned something new today! Thank you :)